# Mountain lion download and compatible issues

Tags: ios, xcode

I need some confirmation regarding Mountain Lion.

1. I am using Snow leopard and considering to upgrade to Mountain Lion. Now while downloading if the internet connection somehow gets disrupted , does it again start from beginning or it pause so i can resume?
2. During downloading, will i be able to use my macbook?
3. I am using Xcode 4.2 with ios base sdk 5.0. Now which Xcode version should i download after installing mountain lion?
4. I have an ipad sdk 5.1.1. Can i use it for device test with new xcode version (right now with my ipad i can not device test)? I searched over ner for solutions but none of them are working for me.

If anyone know about these please inform me. Thanks for your help

Samin

Comment: Huh, I thought you need to go through each version in between in order to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download will probably pause, you can use the mac during downloading, not installing, for ios 5.1.1 i'd download the ios 6 developer preview Xcode to ensure compatibility

Comment: @Samin Personally, I'd advise sticking with production versions of Xcode (e.g. Xcode 4.4 supports iOS 5.1.1 devices without incident). I think a lot of developers are probably sticking with 4.3.3 until Xcode 4.4 has had a few iterations, though I've been fine with 4.4. I definitely would not advise going to Xcode 4.5 (i.e. the iOS 6 beta 4) unless you're planning on testing iOS 6 features. You certainly not supposed to submit apps to the store using beta Xcode versions. So try Xcode 4.5 if you want to play around, but stick with Xcode 4.3 or 4.4 for production code.

Answer (score 4):

1. It does pause, however, it continues as soon as a stable connection is confirmed (automatically if I remember my experience correctly).
2. Yes, your MacBook is completely useable during the download period.
3. You should be running Xcode 4.4 (which can be downloaded without a paid developer account [here](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)) after your install completes.  If you have a paid account, it is best to download Xcode 4.5 Beta 4 along with the iOS 6 SDK.
4. Yes.  Xcode versions 4.3+ support iOS 5.1+.